# Looking for a source to explain the Process of Topological twisting

Tags: hilbert-space, resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, topological-field-theory, superalgebra

as the title suggests I am looking for papers or other material that explains the notion of Topological twisting as it appears in the context of certain SUSY algebras. Concretely I am interested in the case of 3-d $\mathcal{N}=4$, but a more general exposition explaining the key aspects would also be fine.

To stress the points of importance: I would like to learn about how R-symmetry on the Q-charges relates to the existence of some linear combination of these charges that "squares to 0" i.e. $\{Q,Q\}=0$. Additionally I would like to know what the subsequent space of sates amounts to and its physical relevance. A key term would be the theory of Hypermultiplets.

Any explanation as an answer would also be greatly appreciated, but I am mainly interested in papers or books that touch upon this topic in a rather rigorous fashion.